# convert to blob file object from blobURL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

I have an image upload component when I upload an image I get the image format as: `blob:http://localhost:3000/243104af-2266-44f5-962e-8d98cdeade57` , now I want to convert it into a blob file object like:

`Blob(1921) {size: 1921, type: "image/jpeg"}
size
:
1921
type
:
"image/jpeg"
__proto__
:
Blob
size
:
(...)
slice
:
ƒ slice()
type
:
(...)
constructor
:
ƒ Blob()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)
:
"Blob"
get size
:
ƒ ()
get type
:
ƒ ()
__proto__
:
Object`

how can I achieve using javascript?

Comment: See this for reference http://jsfiddle.net/Jan_Miksovsky/yy7Zs/

Comment: @user869375 does this do the same thing I am looking for?

Comment: Try from 3rd line onwards where he gets the blob